# Vercel no longer attempting deploys on push to github

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel

I have been using vercel with my Next.js project to deploy preview and live versions of some sites. Pushing to either the preview branch or main branch causes these deployments automatically in Vercel. However, all of a sudden Vercel is no longer attempting to deploy when I push to github. There are no logs or anything there is just no new deployment. I have confirmed on github that the pushes are going through. I am not sure why Vercel is suddenly not keeping up to date with my github when I am pushing changes to it. I saw something in the docs about how deployments could be blocked after changing the vercel.json file which I did happen to change. But after checking that is not when my deployments stopped working. Has anyone had any experience like this? Adding the link to my github repo below. The preview branch is the one with the most recent commits.

https://github.com/jedwards4044/next-website

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, they have issue with GitHub deployments. 
Please, check status here: https://www.vercel-status.com/

Comment: Have there been any updates? Will our deployments eventually attempt to push, *as in they are just taking longer than normal*? Or will they never push?